# Query with bounding box using API v1.1 academic research

Tags: python, twitter

Using the twitter API v1.1 can I create bounding box query and crawl tweets within dates intervals? I am using academic research

This this the coordinates I want to use:

> 33.1503747135,34.9771672337,33.5070196309,35.2660553074